# how to eliminate new line in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am having problem over the following syntax:

```
 for x in range(0, 10):
       print(x, ' ', end="")
```

I saw the syntax on a tutorial, however when I try it, it is giving me error. The goal I am trying to reach is printing 0 to 9 while eliminating new line. In other words, print 0 to 9 in a single line. Can you tell me what's wrong with the syntax if there is any?

Comment: I know it is basic staff and at the same time, it is fundamental

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? Also, what's the error you're getting?

Comment: I checked the python version I have and looks like I it is version 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print in Python 2.7 without the line break you just need to add an extra comma to the end. It will also add a space between the numbers.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print x,
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the default python version from 2 to 3?

Comment: You need to install version 3, or are you saying that you already have both versions on you computer and want the `python` call to equal a `python3` call?

Comment: I have also changed the default python to version 3 by using this command alias python=python3

Comment: However, still when I try to run the python file, the same error persists

Comment: The alias set will only be active for the current terminal session you are on (unless you configure it to a file like `bashrc`). Are you saying the on a terminal session you type `alias python=python3` and then immediately run the python script, that it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using python 2? Because `print()` with `end` keyword argument is a Python 3 command.

Comment: Ok. that makes sense

Comment: I checked the python version I have and looks like I it is version 2.7

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: I am using terminal to run the python and for some reason it is using the python2.7 version instead of python3

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function with keyword `end` of Python 3 can be imported into Python 2 by
importing from `__future__` at the very beginning of the script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

However, Python 2's `print` statement allows a syntax form without parentheses. This syntax will break with this import.

Comment: instead of importing python 3 end keyword to python 2, why not make the default python version 3 rather than 2

Comment: is that possible?

Comment: @AvaLucas Choose the Python version (2 or 3) and adapt the script accordingly, for example, see "[Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)". If you do not need modules, that require Python 2, then Python 3 is recommended for new projects.

Comment: I have already changed the default version to 3. Yet, still getting invalid syntax

Comment: @AvaLucas Then, make a question with the error message and the code that causes the error.